# Парсинг таблицы xml в sql

Tags: php, java, sql, xml

Программа формирует xml файл, подобного формата.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<timetable>
   <teachers options="import:disable,canadd,canremove,canupdate,primarytt,silent" columns="id,name">
      <teacher id="*1" name="Ivanov Ivan"/>
      <teacher id="*2" name="Petrovskii Vasilii"/>
      <teacher id="*3" name="Sidorova Maria"/>
   </teachers>
   <classes options="import:disable,canadd,canremove,canupdate,primarytt,silent" columns="id,name">
      <class id="*1" name="11a"/>
      <class id="*2" name="10b"/>
      <class id="*3" name="8a"/>
   </classes>
   <subjects options="import:disable,canadd,canremove,canupdate,primarytt,silent" columns="id,name">
      <subject id="*1" name="Matematika"/>
      <subject id="*2" name="Fizica"/>
      <subject id="*3" name="Himia"/>
   </subjects>
   <classrooms options="import:disable,canadd,canremove,canupdate,primarytt,silent" columns="id,name">
      <classroom id="*1" name="cab 1"/>
      <classroom id="*2" name="cab 22"/>
      <classroom id="*3" name="cab 6"/>
   </classrooms>
   <cards options="import:disable,canadd,canremove,canupdate,primarytt,silent" columns="day,period,subjectid,teacherids,classroomids">
      <card subjectid="*1" teacherids="*1" classroomids="*3" day="2" period="1"/>
      <card subjectid="*2" teacherids="*3" classroomids="2" day="3" period="4"/>
      <card subjectid="*3" teacherids="*2" classroomids="*2" day="2" period="3"/>
   </cards>
</timetable>
```

Каким образом можно спарсить последнюю таблицу "cards" в sql, при этом чтобы место ид, были значения этих элементов?

Comment: с чем именно у вас сложность возникает? Возьмите simple_xml, откройте файл, обратитесь к узлу. прочитайте дочерние. соберите insert запрос; если я правильно понимаю вашу задачу

Comment: Да,Вы правильно поняли, однако я нуб в этой области и нужно было примерное направление, как это решить. Попытаюсь почитать про simple_xml, надеюсь получиться.

Comment: Люди помогите набросать основную структуру, знания по этому вопросу у меня близится к нулю, а от мануалов уже голова квадратная.

Comment: вы прочли про основы использования Simple XML (http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php) ? Удалось вам загрузить этот XML и получить доступ к узлам? поделитесь кодом своим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что вам надо необходимо сделать - загрузить этот XML. Тут все просто:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
```

Далее определиться какие столбцы (атрибуты) вас интересуют. Либо вы уже знаете набор, либо вы хотите использовать те, что указаны в атрибуте `columns`:

```
$cols = explode(',', (string)$xml->cards['columns']);
// $cols = ['subjectid', 'teacherids'];               //если знаете
```

Далее XML узлы `card` нужно перевести в вид массива. Определим для этого функцию, которая вычленит нам только нужные атрибуты:

```
$map = function($card) use ($cols){
            $result = [];
            foreach($cols as $c){
                $result[$c] = (string)$card[$c];
            }
            return $result;
        };
```

У вас там в ключах звездочки присутствуют, будем считать, что атрибуты строковые. Иначе приводили бы к `(int)`, например.

Далее пройдемся по элементам и построим массив данных:

```
$data = [];

foreach($xml->cards->card as $card){
    $data[] = $map($card);
}
```

на данном этапе получим массив вида

```
 [0] => Array (
        [day] => 2
        [period] => 1
        [subjectid] => *1
        [teacherids] => *1
        [classroomids] => *3
    )
 ........
```

Теперь необходимо подключиться к БД, используйте, например `PDO`. Также нужен текст SQL запроса для вставки данных. Опять же, либо мы знаем какие у нас столбцы и сколько значений, либо нет. В случае, когда не знаем, используем нечто вида:

```
 $sql = "insert into xxx (".
                implode(',', $cols) .
            ")\n values (".
                implode(',', array_fill( 0, count($cols), '?')) .
            ");";
```

Если же знаем, то просто пишем запрос а-ля

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO xxx (subjectid, teacherids) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

*Обратите внимание,  что в общем случае наименования столбцов должны быть экранированы, в случае mysql это обратные кавычки, для MS SQL - квадратные скобки `[]`, и т.д. Либо убедиьтся, что переданные строки - валидные идентификаторы названий столбцов и входят в ваш "белый список" столбцов.*

На этом шаге получаем следующий  текст запроса:

```
insert into xxx (day,period,subjectid,teacherids,classroomids)
   values (?,?,?,?,?);
```

Теперь подготавливаем запрос, и выполняем его для каждого элемента массива:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$st = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach($data as $d){
    $st->execute($d);
}
```

Здесь стоит отметить, что для относительно большого объема данных выполнения отдельного запроса на каждую вставку - плохая практика. Лучше  будет разбить массив `$data` на части, элементов по 300-500 и использовать вариант запроса на вставку сразу нескольких строк `insert ... values (...), (...), (...)`.
Да в целом плохо в любом случае, но в рамках данного вопроса  оставим так.

Ну а в целом, если XML документ достаточно большой, мегабайт 50 уже будет достаточно, чтобы Simple XML уже слег на загрузке файла. В подобных случаях используют SAX-парсеры, которые не загружают весь документ в память.

---

*дополнение. пропустил часть про значения.*

в общем говоря, считаем что поля список полей нам известен. Опредялем функции для загрузки справочников и маппинга карточек.

```
$loadRefs = function($xml, $refs){
                $result = [];
                foreach($refs as $r ){
                    foreach($xml->$r->children() as $entry){
                        $id = (string)$entry['id'];
                        $result[$r][$id] = (string)$entry['name'];
                    }
                }
                return $result;
            };

$map = function($card) use ($refs){
            return [
                'day' => (int)$card['day'],
                'period' => (int) $card['period'],
                'subject' => $refs['subjects'][ (string)$card['subjectid'] ],
            ];
        };
```

вызываем их и вносим результат в базу, как и ранее

```
$refs = $loadRefs($xml, ['classes', 'teachers', 'subjects']);
$data = [];

foreach($xml->cards->card as $card){
    $data[] = $map($card);
}

$pdo = new PDO(...);
$sql = "INSERT INTO xxx (`day`, period, subject) VALUES (?,?,?);";

$st = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($data as $d){
    $st->execute($d);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробную схему, однако остаётся вопрос с присвоением значения атрибутам, т.е  [teacherids] => *1 должен по ID подставить name "Ivanov Ivan" . Массив должен быть вида : [0] => Array (
        [day] => 2
        [period] => 1
        [subjectid] => Matematika
        [teacherids] => Ivanov Ivan
        [classroomids] => cab 6
    )

Comment: @madblackjack дополнил ответ, но это не нормальная форма для БД.

Comment: @ teran извините за назойливость. VALUES откуда берёт значения? Потому-что форма (?,?,?) ничего не отсылает в базу mysql.

Comment: @madblackjack http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: помогите пожалуйста функция $loadRefs не работает, не могу найти причину

Comment: @madblackjack ну дак вы сделайте `print_r($refs)` после вызова и посмотрите что там вернулось.

Comment: Array ( [classes] => Array ( [*1] => 11a [*2] => 10b [*3] => 8a ) [teachers] => Array ( [*1] => Ivanov Ivan [*2] => Petrovskii Vasilii [*3] => Sidorova Maria ) [subjects] => Array ( [*1] => Matematika [*2] => Fizica [*3] => Himia ) [classrooms] => Array ( [*1] => cab 1 [*2] => cab 22 [*3] => cab 6 ) )

Comment: Вроде формируется массив с данными, однако в $data запроса нет :  Array ( [0] => Array ( [day] => 2 [period] => 1 [subject] => [teacher] => [classroom] => ) [1] => Array ( [day] => 3 [period] => 4 [subject] => [teacher] => [classroom] => ) [2] => Array ( [day] => 2 [period] => 3 [subject] => [teacher] => [classroom] => ) )

Comment: @madblackjack вызов `$refs = loadRefs()` перенесите перед определением функции `$map`, либо передайте `$refs`  туда как параметр, а не через `use`

Comment: teran огромное спасибо, все работает.